# Is the following table for a simple music database in 3NF? If not why?

Tags: database-design, normalization

Im new to databases and I'm struggling to get my head around third normal form (3NF). I have been given a csv file where each record has fields `song`, `album`, `artist` and numerous `tags`.  I have put the data in a database and want to know if it's in 3NF. The headings of the tables I have inserted the data into are below:

1. `| Track_Id | Track_Name | Track_Artist | Track_Album |`
2. `| Tag_Id | Tag_Name |`
3. `| Track_Id | Tag_Id |`

I believe the candidate keys in the first table are `Track_Id` and the combination of `{Track_Name, Track_Artist, Track_Album}`.

I know alternatively I could have a separate `song` table with a foreign key pointing to an `album` table which in turn has a foreign key making a reference to an `artist` table, but is this necessary?

Comment: "But is this necessary?" is not a question that can be easily answered. You are talking about scope of the code not the coding of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If `Track_Id` and `(Track_Name, Track_Artist, Track_Album)` are candidate keys, with no other partial or transitive dependencies, then the table is in 3NF. Think about this - can `Track_Name` determine `Track_Album` or `Track_Artist`, or can `Track_Album` determine `Track_Artist`? If not, it's in 3NF.

If the other two tables have candidate keys, they'll be in 3NF.